# Implement a For loop in MooTools

Tags: javascript, for-loop, mootools

I have to use Mootools for a website but being a real newbie I'm stuck with my code:

```
  var val = element.get('value');
  // Here I get a number between 1 and 6 and I'd like to implement a loop that goes from 1 to the value of val (between 1 and 6) 
  $('jj_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required']");
  $('mm_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required']");
  $('aaaa_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required']");
  $('last_name_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
  $('first_name_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
```

Comment: MooTools is a JavaScript library. You should learn JavaScript before you go learning a JavaScript library. This is a *very* basic (fundamental) JavaScript question which you will easily find solutions to in any JavaScript tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Mootools question, just a javascript question.

```
for (var counter = 1; counter < val; counter++) {
    //Loop code
}
```

Comment: Teaching good JavaScript style from the start is a good idea. It's fairly universally accepted JavaScript style that function calls should be `fn()` and statements like `for` should be `for ()` rather than `for()`, to differentiate them slightly more from function calls which they clearly are not. For these reasons have I edited your answer to insert the space.

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = element.get('value').clean().toInt();

for (var ii = 1; ii <= val; ++ii) {
    $('jj_enfant' + ii).addClass("validate['required']");
    $('mm_enfant' + ii).addClass("validate['required']");
    $('aaaa_enfant' + ii).addClass("validate['required']");
    $('last_name_enfant' + ii).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
    $('first_name_enfant' + ii).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
}

// or... 

while(val--) {
    $('jj_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required']");
    $('mm_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required']");
    $('aaaa_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required']");
    $('last_name_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
    $('first_name_enfant' + val).addClass("validate['required','nodigit']");
}
```